# Signalr not working on production microsoft azure virtual machine 2016 but working in devlopment server

Tags: iis, signalr

```
this is my connection code
```

chatHub = $.connection.chatHub;

```
        $.connection.logging = true;
        $.connection.hub.start({ transport: 'longPolling' }).done(function () {
            registerEvents(chatHub)
```

Comment: Did you get any error messages?

Comment: no i am not getting any error

Comment: when i am working on development then working well.but on production not working

Comment: Are there no error messages in the event viewer and console?

Comment: there is not any error

Comment: Please reply if any one have ans